# How to find elapsed time in milliseconds by compare two timestamps in java

Tags: java, oracle, time, timestamp, elapsedtime

I need to find elapsed time in milliseconds by comparing current time in timestamp with created timestamp in java

For example

```
Updated Timestamp from DB column : 26/07/20 12:00:19.330000000 PM
Current Timestamp : 26/07/20 11:55:19.330000000 AM
```

Timeout configured 2 mins

To get current timestamp,

```
  public static Timestamp getTimestampinGMT(Date date) {
      DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
      df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
      String strCurrentTimeInGMT = df.format(date);
      return Timestamp.valueOf(strCurrentTimeInGMT);
  }
```

And I'm converting updated timestamp column from DB to millisecond

```
Timestamp.valueOf(createtime).getTime()
```

Timeout configured 2 mins is converted to millsec,

```
TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(2);
```

Is there any best way to compare timestamp and calculate the elapsed time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get your updated timestamp as a date-time object from the database. Add two minutes to obtain the timeout time. Compare to the current time.

```
    ResultSet rs = yourPreparedStatement.executeQuery();
    if (rs.next()) {
        OffsetDateTime odt = rs.getObject("your_db_column", OffsetDateTime.class);
        OffsetDateTime currentTime = OffsetDateTime.now(odt.getOffset());
        OffsetDateTime timeoutOdt = odt.plus(TIMEOUT);
        if (currentTime.isAfter(timeoutOdt)) {
            System.out.println("Timed out");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Not timed out yet");
        }
    }
```

I have assumed a `TIMEOUT` constant of type `Duration`. That's flexible in that it will allow you to define the timeout in minutes or milliseconds or which unit you prefer. For example:

```
private static final String CONFIGUTRED_TIMEOUT = "PT2M"; // get from configuration
private static final Duration TIMEOUT = Duration.parse(CONFIGUTRED_TIMEOUT);
```

The configured timeout of `PT2M` may look funny. Read as a period of time of 2 minutes. The format is ISO 8601. You may alternatively use for example `Duration.ofMinutes(2)` or `Duration.ofMillis(120_000)`.

If the datatype in your Oracle database is `timestamp with time zone`, which is recommended, you should be able to retrieve it as an `OffsetDateTime` as shown. You may also try `ZonedDateTime` or `Instant`. If the column in the database hasn't got any time zone, retrieve as `LocalDateTime` and convert to the proper time zone using its `atZone` method.

The date and time classes you tried to use, `Date`, `DateFormat`, `SimpleDateFormat`, `TimeZone` and `Timestamp`, are all poorly designed and all long outdated. Avoid using those.